# Arrays in string Rather than Int

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array I'm using but when I realized I needed to use Decimal Points in my code and Make it so that The array labels itself

When printed, Like so:

Enter rental for month [1]: 231.1

Enter rental for month [2]: 321.3 etc.

```
Scanner keyboardScanner = new Scanner(System.in);  
int[] array;
array = new int[12];



// creates for loop 
for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter Rental for month[]");
    array[i] = keyboardScanner.nextInt();
}

for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) 
{
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Any help Is appreciated! I just need to do the above two points, Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you don't need an integer, you need something like `BigDecimal`. (You *could* use `double`, but that's inappropriate for currency values.) The "labels" part is a separate issue - think about either using `String.format` or string concatenation. You should also try to format your code more readably, and I'd recommend initializing variables at the point of declaration.

Comment: Could you show me an example on the Above code because I don't follow.. I'm a newbie in all forms of coding..

Comment: System.out.println("Enter Rental for month[" + i + "]"); 
This will give you output: enter rental for month [1] and so on

Comment: I suggest you read up on the `double` and `BigDecimal` types then :)

Comment: Scanner keyboardScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       double[] array = new double[12];

       // creates for loop 
       for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
      {
       System.out.println("Enter Rental for month[" + i + "]"));
       array[i] = keyboardScanner.nextDouble();
      }

      for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) 
    {
    System.out.println(array[i]);
    }

PS: I dont know how to do proper formatting of code in comment. Try this

Comment: @ayushi, If you are trying to offer a solution, please write an answer rather than trying to shove code into a comment.

Comment: @ayushi Could you post it as an answerr? then I would be able to Vote it as a correct answer for others who have this problem.

Comment: @merlin2011, thanks.. I will take your advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Scanner keyboardScanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
    double[] array = new double[12]; 
    // creates for loop
    for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
    { 
    System.out.println("Enter Rental for month[" + i + "]"));
     array[i] = keyboardScanner.nextDouble();
    } 
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) 
    { 
    System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It Cannot find symbol, Variable i?

Comment: It happened because the first for statement got commented. you can learn java from tutorialspoint if you are a beginner. That's where I started from. You should know which line is doing what.

Comment: Thanks alot! Fixed it completely